# When does play begin in Euchre?

Tags: euchre

I'm the dealer.  The person to the left tells me to pick it up.  He plays before I discard.  As a result of the fast play, I forget to discard, and in the end of the play, I'm obviously holding onto one extra card.  Does the official play begin at the discard?  Or am I penalized for not discarding?

Comment: The original title was entirely valid. Removing the name of the game in question makes it a vague and unclear title; such removal is not helpful.

Comment: @Nij I think part of the issue was that prefacing the question title with "Euchre:" is really unnatural and not how questions are usually written on this site. I changed the word "Euchre" to be part of the question to be more natural, but still keep that information. Does that seem like a fair compromise?

Comment: Much more natural, yes.

Answer (score 6):

Officially play does not begin until the dealer has discarded.

(take the following quote with a grain of salt, there are tons of euchre variants and home rules that may contradict this).

http://www.euchrelinks.com/rules.html

> XIII. If the eldest-hand leads before the dealer has discarded, he
>   cannot withdraw his card and change his lead, nor can the dealer be
>   deprived of his right to play alone. The discard is not completed
>   until the dealer places his card under the kitty, or on the table, and
>   has quitted it; and when the dealer has once quitted the discarded
>   card, he cannot change it.
>
> XVIII. If any player plays with six or more cards, or, if the dealer
>   plays and omits to discard and fails to announce the fact before three
>   tricks have been turned, such player or dealer cannot count the point,
>   or points, made on their side in the hand, and they lose the deal. But
>   if the adverse party win under such circumstances, they are entitled
>   to count all they make.

If you had stopped play and discarded after the first card(s) were played, they cannot be un-play their card once you discard (and you can use that information to choose a discard).

Since you did not discard and played the hand with 6 cards, you cannot score points this hand.

Comment: Might be worthwhile re-emphasizing in the last sentence that the failure to discard does not prevent *non-dealing* side from scoring.

Comment: In this particular case, the dealer side won the round, but when caught with the extra card, the non-dealer team gave themselves 2 points because dealer played with 6 cards.  I don't think that is covered in any rules I've found.